# How do I prevent a makefile from rebuilding itself twice?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile (GNU Make), with rules like the following:

```
Makefile: dep1
    ...rebuild makefile...

config:
    ...rebuild makefile...
```

However, sometimes when I run `make config`, `dep1` is newer than `Makefile` and so `Makefile` gets rebuilt twice.  This is a waste of my time.  How do I prevent this from happening?

To clarify, the `Makefile` target will rebuild the makefile when the files used to generate it change.  The `config` target allows you to force the makefile to be rebuilt and ignores caches, e.g., when the system configuration changes.

Comment: Why are you rebuilding the makefile in the config recipe?  If you have two different recipes that build the same file and make decides both targets are out of date, then the file will get built twice.  There's nothing make can do about it: it has no idea what the recipes that you give it actually do.

Comment: What do you mean "Why are you rebuilding the makefile in the config recipe?"  That's the purpose of the `config` recipe, to rebuild the makefile.  I'm not expecting Make to look inside my rules and figure things out, I'm expecting something *I* can do to prevent the double rebuild.

Comment: What I mean is that generally in make you only want to have one recipe that builds any given target.  If you have two recipes build the same target then you may do twice the work.  That's what prerequisites are for.  However, in this case where you're rebuilding `Makefile` it's even less necessary because make always tries to rebuild the makefile all by itself: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html  So basically, you always know that `Makefile` is up to date before you even start to run the `config` target.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a poorly-documented variable called [`MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html), which lists the goals specified on the command line.  This variable does not appear anywhere in the documentation index, and does not appear in the section on special variables, even though the documentation calls it a "special variable"!

Here is the solution:

```
ifneq (config,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
Makefile: dep1
    ...rebuild makefile...
endif

config:
    ...rebuild makefile...
```

Comment: It does appear in the index: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Name-Index.html#Name-Index_fn_letter-M  It's documented in the section describing command line goals.  Probably it should also be described in "Special Variables".